# Calculating the p-value for a marker of disease

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, medicine

I'm trying to calculate p-values for a research project.  Basically, it is to see if the amount of white blood cells in a patient's sample correlates to a certain disease.

Null hypothesis: # of white blood cells does not correlate to cellulitis

I have a collection of white blood cells in patients proven not to have cellulitis, and collection of # of white blood cells in patients shown to have cellulitis.

Could anyone help me out or point me towards some resources so I can calculate this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read about an unpaired (two sample) t test in any statistical text, and I think you'll be on your way.

Comment: that's right, as Harvey stated, just look at a t-test for equality of means between two samples (with and without cellulitis)